# Activesync mark mail as read

Tags: activesync

I am developing an application which uses activesync protocol.

To mark mail as read i am using Sync command and below is my request

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Sync xmlns:email="Email" xmlns:tasks="Tasks" xmlns="AirSync">
    <Collections>
        <Collection>
            <SyncKey>42496781</SyncKey>
            <CollectionId>5</CollectionId>
            <DeletesAsMoves>1</DeletesAsMoves>
            <GetChanges>0</GetChanges>
            <WindowSize>512</WindowSize>
            <Commands>
                <Change>
                    <ServerId>5:31</ServerId>
                    <ApplicationData>
                        <email:Read>1</email:Read>
                    </ApplicationData>
                </Change>
            </Commands>
        </Collection>
    </Collections>
</Sync>
```

Above works well with hosted account but for non hosted account it is not working. For non hosted account some times i am getting status error 8 or 3.

Answer (score 0):

Status errors for Sync command are here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg675457(v=exchg.80).aspx

3 = Invalid synchronization key.

8 = Object not found.